# datepicker binding in knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, binding, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use JQuery's datepicker in conjunction with knockout using bindingHandlers. When I click on the textboxes, it shows the datepicker. but the underlying model is not updated.

== Script

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dtp = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        $(element).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (evntObj) {
                $(element).datepicker("hide");
                valueAccessor($(element).val());
            }

        });
    }
}
function Member(item) {
        var self = this;
        self.JoinDate = ko.observable(item.JoinDate);
}
 var viewmodel = function () {

        self = this;
        self.members = ko.observableArray([]);
 }
var moView = new viewmodel();
moView.push(new Member({JoinDate:"10-10-2010"}))
moView.push(new Member({JoinDate:"11-11-2011"}))
ko.applyBindings(moView);
```

== HTML

```
<table data-bind='foreach: members()'>
    <tr><td><input type="text" data-bind=" value: JoinDate, dtp:{}" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/fer146ap/

There seems to be other issues popping when simulating in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your JavaScript errors by moving the `new Member` `push` calls into your `viewmodel`.

I have also implemented a solution based on some code found here: [knockout datepicker custom binding](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X82aC/) which looks to be the behavior you are after.

The updated binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dtp = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().dtpOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);   
        }
    }
};
```

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fer146ap/6/) code accordingly. Also I always like to use `Moment.js` when working with dates, however you can remove this if you see fit.

Hope that helps!